# Iterate over find command's output with exec or xargs & pass this as paramater to script

Tags: bash, exec, xargs

I have to find files & execute a python command on them. There are several thousand files that `find` command finds. So, instead of running a for loop to iterate over the output of `find` command, I'm trying to do an `xargs` over find output.

I am unable to work out how to pass the output of find command as parameter to the script.

```
find "$DIRLOC" -iname "*.html" |
xargs python3 src/shell/updates/python/updateshere.py <filename from find command's output to go here> "$HASH" {} \;
```

Please could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```bash
find "$DIRLOC" -iname "*.html" -print0 |
xargs -0 -I {} python3 src/shell/updates/python/updateshere.py {} "$HASH"
```

Used `-print0` option in `find` and `-0` in `xargs` to handle filename/directory names with space or other special characters.

You can handle all in `find` also using `-exec` option:

```bash
find "$DIRLOC" -iname "*.html" -exec \
python3 src/shell/updates/python/updateshere.py {} "$HASH" \;
```

Comment: Thank you ver much Anubhava. Just what I've been after. It works so well.